# use Jquery add size="5" into select

Tags: jquery, select

I'm new to jQuery, I just wondering how to add size="5" into select. Many thanks.

e.g. change

```
<select>
    <option value="123">123</option>
</select>
```

into:

```
<select size="5">
    <option value="123">123</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, `size` is an attribute, so you can use the [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method.

```
$(your selector here).attr('size', '5');
```

Answer (score 2):

Add an attribute using [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
$("select").attr("size", "5")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("select").attr("size", "5");
```

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
​$("#sel").attr('size',5);​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

where `sel` id the id of `select`